# sum a not enabled text box enabled as a zero

Tags: vb.net

i'am using 9 textboxes in one form and i want the application to sum the numbers into another label in another form , the user not have to fill all of the 9 text boxes,so i used a 9 checkboxes to enable every textbox separately.
the problem is when i hit the button that suppose to make the sum equation without checking all of the 9 checkboxes and fill the 9 textboxes the application stops and shows an error.
i want to sum a textbox.enabled = false
as zero
and that's my button code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Me.Hide()
   Form5.Show()
   Dim intNum1 As Decimal
   Dim intNum2 As Decimal
   Dim intNum3 As Decimal
   Dim intNum4 As Decimal
   Dim intNum5 As Decimal
   Dim intNum6 As Decimal
   Dim intNum7 As Decimal
   Dim intNum8 As Decimal
   Dim intNum9 As Decimal
   intNum1 = Decimal.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
   intNum2 = Decimal.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
   intNum3 = Decimal.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
   intNum4 = Decimal.Parse(TextBox4.Text)
   intNum5 = Decimal.Parse(TextBox5.Text)
   intNum6 = Decimal.Parse(TextBox6.Text)
   intNum7 = Decimal.Parse(TextBox7.Text)
   intNum8 = Decimal.Parse(TextBox8.Text)
   intNum9 = Decimal.Parse(TextBox9.Text)
   Form5.Label1.Text = intNum1 + intNum2 + intNum3 + intNum4 + intNum5 + intNum6 + intNum7 + intNum8 + intNum9
```

Comment: Please show some efford and code.

Comment: Please give us more informations about your code. And take a look at this page to know [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I find this very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
intNum1 = Val(TextBox1.Text)
```

Instead of

```
intNum1 = Decimal.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
```